# How do I change the size of the menu bar in gnome

Tags: gnome, themes

I am trying out Ubuntu 16.10 with the gnome interface. I like it, except for 1 thing. The menu bar on my application windows is too big for me. (I have a 14" screen, 1366x768).

Does anybody know in which theme file I can change this, and how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who is interested, I installed a shell theme. The menu bar is now much thinner. So, it can obviously be done.